# protractor + cucumber waits and timesout without executing the full test

Tags: protractor, pageobjects, cucumberjs

I'm implementing E2E tests using Protractor with CucumberJS. The problem i am facing is it executes only 1st step and waits till it gets timedout. This issue only when using page object.

Here is my feature file:

Scenario: validate adding incident weight
  Given adding priority program
  And adding incident weight type
  And user creates incident
  Then Incident weight should be displayed correctly.

Page Object file:

```
var createincidentpage = function(){    

    this.priorityAdd = function(userdetail, callback) {
        browser.ignoreSyncronization = true;
        incidentSection.click()

        .then(function(){
            return PPPage.click();
        }).then(function(){
            browser.switchtTo().frame(0);
            return newElement.click();
        }).then(fucntion(){
            return newppname.sendkeys("xyz");
        }).then(function(){
            return fromDatePicker.click();
        }).then(function(){
            return gotoTodayElement.click();
        }).then(function(){
            return editableOk.Click();
        }).then(function(){
            return toDatePicker.click();
        }).then(function(){
            return selDateinMOnth.click();
        }).then(function(){
            SubmitButton.click();
            return callback();
        });
    };

module.exports =  new createincidentpage();
```

My Step file:

```
var createincidentpage = require ('../pages/createincidentpage.js');

Given('priority program add' , function (callback) {
    createincidentpage.priorityAdd(function callback(){
       callback();
    }):
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you not invoke the `callback()` inside `priorityAdd()`.

To make more clear, I rename some variable in following code.

You have to call the `callback()` comes from `Given()`, otherwise the runtime can't end the `Given()` and wait until timeout as you met.

You call the `callback()` inside `Given()` directly or pass down the `callback` into nested function as you did and call it inside nested function.

```
var createincidentpage = function(){    

    this.priorityAdd = function(userdetail) {
        browser.ignoreSyncronization = true;
        incidentSection.click()

        PPPage.click();      
        browser.switchtTo().frame(0);
        newElement.click();
        newppname.sendkeys("xyz");
        fromDatePicker.click();
        gotoTodayElement.click();
        editableOk.Click();
        toDatePicker.click();
        selDateinMOnth.click();
        return SubmitButton.click();
    };

module.exports =  new createincidentpage();
```

Step file:

```
var createincidentpage = require ('../pages/createincidentpage.js');

//Option 1, invoke `callback`
Given('priority program add', function(callback) {
    createincidentpage.priorityAdd().then(function(){
       return callback();
    });
});

// Option 2, return a promise like object, recommend to use option 2
Given('adding incident weight type', function(){
    return createincidentpage.priorityAdd();
});
```

Comment: i returned callback() as mentioned but now i see a new error: "Maximum size of stack exceeded". This is how my function looks now:

Comment: this.priorityAdd = function (callback){

//performing navigation ..clicks & add values and finally submit

editableOK.click();
}).then(function(){
ppSubmitButton.click();
return callback(); // what do i return here as i am not asserting anything
});
};


Step file:

Given('prioprity program type is added' , function(callback){
 createIncpage.priorityAdd( function callback(){
 callback();
});
});

Comment: Thankyou .i updated as you mentioned but i see anew error now: "maximum stack exceeded". Also, since i m not asserting anything in the function priorityAdd() -- i m not sure what to return other than  "return callback() ".

Comment: please update the `priorityAdd()` with your code. Don't leave it empty, so that I can know how to modify your real code.  The error: "Maximum size of stack exceeded"   indicated your code run into dead loop.   Don't put the code of `priorityAdd()` in comment,  add it into your question body.

Comment: Updated my current code and the error is "Maximum size of stack exceeded

Comment: You made a type error in following code: `}).then(fucntion(){ return newppname.sendkeys("xyz");`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yong. Both the options didn't work. Option1 threw error: cannot resolve promise of undefined. & option2 skipped the execution with testresult as pass.